# getActiveNotifications return null

Tags: android

i am trying to read all current notifications.
Here is my Service:

```
public class MyService extends NotificationListenerService{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        StatusBarNotification[] notifications = getActiveNotifications();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

and my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

and of course my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ginso.stepwatcher">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but when i debug the service, `getActiveNotifications()` returns `null`.
What am i doing wrong? do i miss any permissions? i am running it on Android 8.0